# Why is the handle of a cup of hot latte is not hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have a cup of very hot Latte. However, the handle of the cup is *never* hot - except the part very closed to the cup, that is *always warm*, but the heat disappears very soon the further away from the cup itself. Even though I have been waiting for quite some time, the handle is still not hot at all. Why?$^\dagger$

---

$\dagger$ The handle of a spoon made of metal never appears to be hot (say, whenever we are having a hot soup), so I wonder if the material is irrelevant here?

Comment: Low thermal conductivity of porcelain? Effective cooling due to plenty of surface area?

Comment: @Steeven I was thinking if the surface area is large enough comparing with the cup itself (which has at least one side is hot latte)

Comment: downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @Shing does my reply help?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely because your cup might be made of porcelain, which has an extremely low thermal conductivity.  Furthermore, most latte cups have a really large opening, so this large surface area will just cause the latte to cool down really quickly.  Alternatively, the presence of a metal spoon would serve as a good thermal conductor to allow the cup to cool down really quickly.  Here I have just listed a few possibilities that you might be experiencing.

Comment: I am not so sure if the material matters? Since given a spoon made of metal in a hot soup. Its handle always appears to be not hot in my experience.

Comment: The metal spoon is a good conductor of heat, so it will conduct heat away from the soup to the air.  So it's hot when you touch it

Comment: Hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Okay, I will do a experiment keep change the water to hot water, and see what will happen.

Comment: You can put hold the spoon that is in contact with the hot water and tell me what you feel... probably would feel hot

Comment: also please check the tick if it helps

Comment: @Shing you could refer to the post on cooling the cup with a spoon.

Comment: I have finally done the experiment, and post it as answer. Feel free to give me suggestion, as I am a poor experimenter...

Answer (score 0):

I have done a few trial runs, and a few observations might shed some light on this question; however, it was done in my home with the most primitive "biological thermometer" - my hands and my face(more sensitive than my hands, and I get nothing better here), so the *uncertainty* is *large*:

> Cover the cup with a cup lid, and exchanging the hot water to just boiled water every 3 to 5 mins, for a total 15 mins.

- *Result I*: No observable heat change for the handle. Hence, the surface area of the Latte exposed to air is more likely to be irrelevant
- *Result II*: the part of the handle near to the cup is merely warm even within 15 mins (it happens to mental spoon too); therefore, low thermal conductivity of porcelain seems to lose the competition to other factors.

Since it is weird that the part very near to the cup gets only warm, while the cup itself gets so hot, so I guess the relevant factor is *cross section type*

> To test my idea, I have soaked the handle in boiled water instead, and *assume* that heat flows through the cross section from the handle to the cup is same as from the cup to the handle: 
>   [image]

During my 1st trial run, the steam from the boiled water had ruined everything, then I have repeated the experiment again with paper blocking the steam -- then, the cup itself (near the handle) gets *quite* warm (even *slightly hot*) in about 3 mins! The heat flow is not symmetric! So my assumption was wrong! Hence it leads to two *possibilities*:

1. Cross section type (structure in between handle and cup is different(?). However, I have no way to tell whether it is true or not.)
2. The area of cross section - during the heat flow, if the cross section area gets smaller and smaller, the heat flow seems to be significantly hindered. (needed to be tested further, I will update it when possible)

---

Not quite relevant, but interestingly related:
I have further done experiment with a strange shape mental spoon. Soaking the spoon's open part (bowl) in hot water for a few seconds,

[image]

For about 90s, the strange shape shoulders was merely warm! While I did it the opposite way - bathing the handle, the thread part got hot quite quickly!

The cross section seems to me somehow must play the major role here.